# Exception in exception constructor

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch

Assume this piece of C++ code:

```
class myexception1
{
public:
    myexception1()
    {};
};

class myexception2
{
public:
    myexception2()
    {
        throw myexception1();
    };
};

void test()
{
    try
    {
        throw myexception2();
    }
    catch (...)
    {
    }
};
```

If I run the `test` function, which kind of exception will receive the catch block? Could this generate some memory leak because throwing an exception from an exception constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception caught will be myexception1. Whether there is a memory leak would depend on what exactly the exception constructor does - in this case there won't be one.

Comment: Thanks for answering.